# How to call text changed event immediately?

Tags: wpf, textbox

I've a text box in that i added a event `TextChanged` but it doesn't giving me all the data i entered in that text box it neglecting last character but i want all chars what i enter in the text box so how can i do this one please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TextChanged event gives you all the character:

```
TextBox currentTextBox = sender as TextBox;
string fullText = CurrentTextBox.Text;
```

Are you sure your not in like a PreviewKeyDownEvent or any other Preview Events. All of these events neglect the last input

Comment: yup! yes currently i'm using previewtextinput now i changed to textchanged its working fine now.. Thank you so much @MyKuLLSKI :)

Answer (score 0):

Make an extended TextBox class and handle the KeyUp event to force an update to the text property binding after each key stroke.

```
public class MyWPFTextBox: TextBox
{
    public MyWPFTextBox(): base()
    { KeyUp += new KeyEventHandler(MyWPFTextBox_KeyUp); }

    private void MyWPFTextBox_KeyUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        BindingExpression BE = GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
        if (BE != null)
            BE.UpdateSource();
    }
}
```

Comment: There's every point if you want to do MVVM properly - i.e. with minimal code behind in the view.

Answer (score -1):

you should look at the **PreviewTextInput** event.

you also should take a look at mvvm pattern, binding and UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged. there you do not need events at all, you get your information via binding.

Comment: PreviewTextInput NEGLECTS the last key!

Comment: good to know, i use just mvvm and binding, so i dont need these events.

Comment: You know your going to have to know these things. Going out of you way to stay in MVVM can cause execution time longer. Call me next time you have a Focus issue